# How to insert records in a table in a text file using COBOL and search and display record(s) which satisfy a condition?

Tags: file-io, cobol

I am trying to write a COBOL program to read an input file "INPUT.TXT" and display the details of students whose RATING='B'.I am using [ http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cobol_online.php ] for my program. The records in "INPUT.TXT" (please note that the input file is a simple text file) are:

```
      EMPID  NAME     COMPANY          RATING

      112211 UMESH    CAPGEMINI        A
      221122 ISHAN    ZALONI           A
      134231 AJMERA   GOOGLE           B
      232144 NIYANTA  WIPRO            B
      561144 KANKANA  ZETA             A
      324556 CHRISTOPHER  TCS          C
      123443 SIDDIKA       TCS         A
```

So far, I have been successful in just displaying the details of all the employees( that too after making a lot of adjustments of the records in the input file). So, I need a fix to the following problems-

```
              1. inserting the records in the form of a table in 'input.txt'

              2. searching for a particular record
```

I am completely unaware as to how to solve my 1st problem.

I don't need the complete program/code. I just need some "specific" advice regarding the topic(s) need I need to cover for my 2nd Problem.

Comment: If you don't need the data for Excel (I don't know where that thought came from) then why have you Accepted the Answer? Look up subscripting. Try Gary Cutler's for GNU COBOL/OpenCOBOL. Look to download GNU COBOL (formerly OpenCOBOL) and you'll get much more flexibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, you could simply use a separator like ; and then you can import the file into excel by giving the separator:

```
01  NEWFILE.                         
      05  EMPID  PIC 9(6).  
      05  FILLER PIC X VALUE ';'.  
      05  NAME   PIC A(10).   
      05  FILLER PIC X VALUE ';'.                      
      05  COMPANY PIC X(17). 
      05  FILLER PIC X VALUE ';'. 
      05  RATING  PIC X(1).
```

To search you can simply go through the file with the same read you used and find the record. If you want to read the file only once, you could store it's content in an array, and use the PERFORM VARYING statement to search in it.

Also, to write into the file, you open it as input/output:

```
OPEN I-O filename
```

Another thing, these things can be found simply in Google, this is basic COBOL.

Comment: if i don't import the file into excel, then, i guess..there is no way of storing it in the form of a table..isn't it??

Comment: Well there are many ways to store data in a table. If you can define the technical meaning of a table (like excel, db2, ...), there is probably a way to do it.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a too simple question for an up vote in my opinion. The voting system is designed to bring up the questions that are relevant and bury the opposite.